# Open image with fancybox and thumbnail on bottom?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I'm working with `fancybox` to open an image.
i want to open an image preview and other image thumbnails in bottom like this

[image]

i looking for long time to make fancy like that but nothing.
how can i achieve what i want?link maybe?

thanks.

Comment: Should not be so hard to code so let me ask you, what have you tried?

Comment: not yet..i want to looking for fancybox with thumbnail completely like that..so i just embed the jquery/fancybox to my page :)

Comment: you can check here. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples . here they had given examples as you need.

Comment: ok thanks..but still suitable with my purpose..any other link ?

Comment: I think you have to code the content the way you wan it as a totally independent and functional page (thumbnails, preview and everything), then just open it using `iframe` mode in fancybox.